# Create TabItems with different UserControl's in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

First of all, I'm kind new to WPF and MVVM, so you can expect some crazy mix here, just suggest changes, I'm here to learn.
This question comes as continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660591/add-tabitems-to-an-existing-tabcontrol-wpf-mvvm).

I have a `TabControl` with some `TabItem`'s defined in `XAML` each of them has his own `UserControl`.
XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.GUI.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPF.GUI.ViewModels"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WPF.GUI.Views"
        xmlns:mainWindow="clr-namespace:WPF.GUI.ViewModels.MainWindow"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WPF.Processing.Model"
        xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPF.GUI.Helpers"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <!--#region Resources-->
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ResultViewModel}">
            <views:ResultView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ConfigurationViewModel}">
            <views:ConfigurationView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailedViewModel}">
            <views:DetailedView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <!--#endregion Resources-->

    <!--#region DataContext-->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <mainWindow:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!--#endregion DataContext-->

    <!--#region Main Grid-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--#region Tabs-->
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Model.TabItemsVM}" x:Key="Tabs"/>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:VMWrap}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding VModel}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>

                    <!--Result Tab-->
                    <TabItem Header="Result">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ResultViewModel}"/>
                    </TabItem>

                    <!--Configuration Tab-->
                    <TabItem Header="Configuration">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ConfigViewModel}"/>
                    </TabItem>

                    <!--Others-->
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tabs}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </TabControl.ItemsSource>
        </TabControl>
        <!--#endregion-->    
    </Grid>
    <!--#endregion Main Grid-->
</Window>
```

If I use the example of the answer linked above is working fine, I can create  tabs individually and Result Tab and Configuration Tab, stays the same.

However if I use a `UserControl` the new `TabItem` I create out of my Collection put my `UserControl` inside the `TabItem.Header`

If I do not follow MVVM and I create a `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` works as expected, so I assume the problem is on the `TabControl.DataTemplate`

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Edit: As I cannot provide a Working example because the complexity of the app and the code involved, I add the following pictures to explain the problem:

[image: Wrong View]
Expected View
[image: Expected View]

Comment: You haven't provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Do you see all tabs except the hardcoded ones or what is your issue?

Comment: I tried..but since it is a complex question, I cannot provide all the necessary code for views and viewsModel because it complains about "So much code on your question". You can tell me what you miss and I can try to provide it with edits.

Comment: A minimal view model and a minimal view that both compile.

Comment: The "hardcoded" tabs dissapear when I add a new Object in the `TabItemsVM`. I will try to prepare a minimal example.

Comment: `ContentPresenter` should only be used inside `ControlTemplate`, rather use `ContentControl`.

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, there are 4 Views with his correspondant viewModel and Model involved in the MainWindow, I cannot provide the minimal working example.

Comment: @Sinatr, okey, I have made the changes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots with the expected result, which is when I have a collection of TabItems instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using `ContentTemplateSelector` inside `TabControl`

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailedTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailedViewModel}">
            <views:DetailedView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ConfigurationTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ConfigurationViewModel}">
            <views:ConfigurationView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ResultTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ResultViewModel}">
            <views:ResultView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <helpers:MyViewSelector x:Key="Selector" 
                                DetailedTemplate="{StaticResource DetailedTemplate}" 
                                ConfigurationTemplate="{StaticResource ConfigurationTemplate}"
                                ResultTemplate="{StaticResource ResultTemplate}"/>

</Window.Resources>
```

`Tab Control`:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    BorderThickness="0.5"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource Selector}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Model.DetailsVM}" x:Key="Tabs"/>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DetailedViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.SelectedItem.FileInfo.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <!--Result View-->
                    <TabItem Header="Import" Content="{Binding ResultViewModel}"/>
                    <!--Configuration Tab-->
                    <TabItem Header="Configuration" Content="{Binding ConfigViewModel}"/>    
                    <!--Others-->
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tabs}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </TabControl.ItemsSource>

</TabControl>
```

Helper

```
    public class MyViewSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object inItem, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (inItem == null)
            {
                return ResultTemplate;
            }

            if (inItem is DetailedViewModel)
            {
                return DetailedTemplate;
            }
            if (inItem is ResultViewModel)
            {
                return ResultTemplate;
            }
            if (inItem is ConfigurationViewModel)
            {
                return ConfigurationTemplate;
            }

            return ResultTemplate;
        }

        public DataTemplate DetailedTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ConfigurationTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate ResultTemplate { get; set; }

    }
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18312765/2315752

https://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/mvvm-using-contenttemplateselector-in-tab-control-view/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx